# What is the R command for making a skatter plot with different variables?

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset for males and females, and I'm supposed to make a scatterplot showing the difference between women and men.

But dont know how to include separate plots for male/female.
Anyone who can help me?:)

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(attractiveness_data)`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `par` you may set `mfrow=c(1, 2)` for one row and two columns. Then `plot` with `subset`.

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(Deviation ~ lg_salary, subset(dat, sex == 1), col=2, main='Sex 1', ylim=range(dat$Deviation))
plot(Deviation ~ lg_salary, subset(dat, sex == 2), col=4, main='Sex 2', ylim=range(dat$Deviation))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 100; set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(lg_salary=runif(n, 5000, 10000),
                  Deviation=rnorm(n),
                  sex=sample(1:2, replace = TRUE))
dat$Deviation[dat$sex == 1] <- dat$Deviation[dat$sex == 1] + rnorm()
dat <- transform(dat, Deviation=ifelse(sex == 1, Deviation + rnorm(1, 3, .5), Deviation))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(Deviation~lg_salary, data = subset(attractiveness_data, Female == 1), col = "pink", main = "Female", xlab = "lg salary")
plot(Deviation~lg_salary, data = subset(attractiveness_data, Female == 0), col = "blue", main = "Male", xlab = "lg salary")
```

Output:

[image]

#### Combine Female and Male in one plot

To combine them you can use the following code:

```
colors <- c("pink", "blue")
plot(Deviation~lg_salary, data = attractiveness_data, col = colors[factor(Female)], main = "Female vs Male", xlab = "lg salary")
legend("topleft", legend = levels(factor(attractiveness_data$Female)), pch = 19, col = colors)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! But how can I get both female and male in the same Figure?

Comment: @Line, I added some code to combine them in one plot.

Comment: Thank you! 

One more question.. In the data set, it is data from both Europe, China and America. If I want to make a figure each for the data I have for the respective countries (with male and female in the same plot) Will I do the same for China and America as I did with the numbers from Europe then?

Comment: @Line yes you can do the same with same code!